# unauthorized address bar requests

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In cakephp (version 2.X)I can authenticate a user but I get problems when a user tries to access from the address bar a webpage it hasnt got access to.
What happens is that I get routed to the base index file with missingControler error.
SO my path is ..../crm/students on a webpage the user should not access and then i get directed to /crm/crm/

I am unclear why I am not getting redirected to the login page and also I have been told to use .htaccess which I dont get how this related to authentication.

Also I tried to use 'before filter' without success to redirect the user

I also checked other stack overflow posts and I am not getting this to work. Could someone point me to the docs where is clarifies unauthorized requests from the address bar?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html
Handling unauthenticated requests

```
  //app controller
```

public $components = array(

```
 "Email",
'Session',
'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'  ),
         'authorize' => array('Controller'), // Added this line   
    // array('DebugKit.Toolbar' => array( 'panels' => array('MyCustom', 'timer'=>false))),
```

));

```
    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // Admin can access every action
      //  debug($user['role']);
       // debug("asdddddddddddddddddddddddddd");

        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
            return true;
        }
       //  return $this->Auth->redirectUrl();
        // Default deny
        return false;
    }




// student  controller
public function isAuthorized($user) {


    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'manager') {
        return true;
    }
   if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'student') {
        return true;
    }

     if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'teacher') {
        return false;
    }



return parent::isAuthorized($user);
```

}

```
 `I have the project in a subfolder which could cause the issue Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); this routes to crm/crm/... again with the` project name repeated and how do i stop this as this is the problem?
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt do anything to kick out an someone from a protected page  public function unauthenticated($request ,$response)
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

Comment: what is `crm` in your path? Is it a routing prefix?

Comment: crm is just the name of the cakephp project and the project is redirecting to the root dir when it shouldnt

Comment: Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); this routes to crm/crm/... again with the project name repeated and how do i stop this as this is the problem?

Comment: I tried again with router Router::connect('../', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); and no luck. I just dont know how to fix this sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with the way Auth component works, if the "unauthorizedRedirect" property isn't set then it seems to redirect to "/{app-directory" which is your domain - hence why you end up at "yourDomain/youDomain".

Easiest way to fix it, in your Auth component in AppController add

```
public $componens = array(
    //other components
    'Auth' => array(
        //other properties
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => 'url to redirect to' //e.g. '/'
    )
);
```

Comment: Good :) Looking at the documentation and the code in the actual file this shouldn't actually be necessary as the defaults should take care of things properly - I'll let you know if I manage to find why the defaults aren't working as expected